# MariaDB Restart Error "unknown variable'default-character-set = cp932'"

Tags: mariadb

I am currently installing MariaDB 10.6 in a Windows 10 64bit environment. Restart MariaDB after writing the following in my.ini:

```
[mariadbd]
datadir = C: / Program Files / MariaDB 10.6 / data
port = 3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2035M
character-set-server = utf8mb4

[client]
port = 3306

[mariadb]
default-character-set = cp932
```

Then I get the following error:

```
2021-07-21 5:29:53 0 [ERROR] C: \ Program Files \ MariaDB 10.6 \ bin \ mariadbd.exe: unknown variable'default-character-set = cp932'
2021-07-21 5:29:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

If anyone knows why the settings described in the [mariadb] group cause an error in mariadbd.exe, it would be helpful.

Comment: use **character-set-server=cp932** instead of **default-character-set = cp932**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because people frequently mistype between the two, the `mariadbd.exe` reads both [mariadb](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.6/include/mysqld_default_groups.h) and `mariadbd` (and others) as a groups.

Clients can use `mariadb-client` or [client-mariadb](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/3d6eb7afcfb47cb432f790d0b25c8c1f4ec5bcf3/client/mysql.cc#L1043).

Connector-c based connectors use [mariadb-client](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/f9996869687827b96b2e1b80fe9f0752a41b889e/libmariadb/ma_default.c#L164) too.

The `--help` option on all server and client programs will show the groups read and options used.

Comment: Thank you very much. solved!
I really appreciate it.